# Pass Dynamic Parameter in Select query in mysql

Tags: mysql

Can you please help me on the below query?

I have below select query, in which i want to pass a parameter dynamically to the hostname column. Is there way to achieve it?

```
select * 
from All_HOSTS 
where hostname='example.com' 
order by FROM_UNIXTIME(start_epoch);
```

In ORACLE we have like this

```
select * from all_hosts where hostname=&1;
```

so it will ask parameter dynamically when I execute the select query - Is there way in MYSQL as well?

Please assist.

Comment: Short answer- no there isn't

Comment: is there any other way apart from the above.? Each and every time i passing paramter to get the details. If there is any other better way - please suggest.