# Insert by reference in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, sqlplus

In Oracle Database (SQL Plus), there is an alternative method to insert values into a table, which my lecturers called "insert by reference". It looks like this:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO table_name ('&col_name1','&col_name2' ...);
Enter value for col_name1: value1
Enter value for col_name1: value1
...
```

This enables you to use the same command repeatedly (by pressing up arrow) to enter multiple records in the table; you only need to enter the specific values separately after executing the command. And there is no need to go back to each value, erase it and type in the new value.

So my question is, is there any way to replicate this handy command in MySQL?

Comment: Not there isn't -didn't you ask this yesterday (or someone on same course perhaps)?

Comment: Definitely not me haha.

Comment: Just coincidence then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979925/pass-dynamic-parameter-in-select-query-in-mysql?noredirect=1#comment113149117_63979925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of sqlplus, not of oracle's, taking advantage of oracle's [prepared statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci05bnd.htm) feature.

You need to find or develop an sql client for mysql that can similarly use mysql's prepared statement feature in a nicer way either directly [through SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) or through an [API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html) (C API is just an example).

We cannot recommend 3rd party tools or utilities here on SO, you need to find the one that best suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I am currently using mycli so maybe I can find a way to add that feature myself!

Answer (score 1):

perhaps use the multi row insert:

```
insert into table_name (col_name1, col_name2)
values (value_1_1, value_1_2), (value_2_1, value_2_2) [...]
```

Comment: That is indeed a quick way to enter records into a table, but I was specifically looking for a method like the one in my question, where you can enter the values seperately. Just for curiosity's sake.